# android - how to get a button from another activity

Tags: android, button, text

If I am one an activity and I know another activity is running, how can I change the button text from that other activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another activity is running but it is in `onPause` and you can't guarantee that activity will not destroy before you going back to there again.

So you should better look at `onResume` of the activity to update the button text.If you still want to change the button text while activity is onPause you can use a broadcast receiver on the activity that will change the text.You can also use a handler along with runnable to update button text.

Answer (score 0):

Change something in persistant storage, like sharedpreferences.

Then in the target activity, override the onResume method to check the persistant storage and perform the change on the button.